# Generic DAO Service using prisma js

Tags: typescript, mongodb, prisma, dao, solid

Hi Im tryng to build a DAO class using prisma aplyng SOLID principles.
The idea is to build generic functions and an abstract class so i can aply them on the diferen modules by dependence injection.
So for example when i need to build my Users.Service.ts
Ill extend GenericClass and inyect the funcions i need for thar module
create, update and so on.
But im having probems with typescript.
At the botom is the entire code for the Generic service.
The error I get from typescript is :

> This expression is not callable.
> Each member of the union type '((args: SelectSubset<T, UsersCreateArgs>) => Prisma__UsersClient<UsersGetPayload, never>) | ((args: SelectSubset<...>) => Prisma__ProductsClient<...>) | ((args: SelectSubset<...>) => Prisma__CartsClient<...>)' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other

What i understund of it is that typescript can be certain about `PrismaClient[T]` being of the same kind that `dto:GenericDto<T>`

I ve builded some validations for it but, doesnt seem to work.
Probably there are a simpler solution for it, but i dont see it .
The abstract class is not yet implemented because im having problems with the firs function.
and the function is outside the class so i can customize my classes depending on the need.

**This is the only implementation that works, but it sucks on scalability**
Does someone knows how to do this the right way?
Thanks so much

```js
import { Prisma, PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
export interface IParam<T extends Lowercase<Prisma.ModelName>> {
  client: PrismaClient[T]
  data: Dto<T>
  model: T
}

type Dto<T extends Lowercase<Prisma.ModelName>> = PrismaClient[T] extends { create: (args: { data: infer U }) => Promise<unknown> } ? U : never
type Models<T extends keyof PrismaClient> =
  PrismaClient[T] extends { create: infer U }
    ? { create: U }
    : never

type createMethodType<T extends Lowercase<Prisma.ModelName>> = (dto: Dto<T>, client: Models<T>) => Promise<unknown>
class CreatorObject {
  constructor (
    public carts = async (dto: Dto<'carts'>, client: Models<'carts'>): Promise<any> => {
      return await client.create({ data: dto })
    },
    public users = async (dto: Dto<'users'>, client: Models<'users'>): Promise<any> => {
      return await client.create({ data: dto })
    },
    public products = async (dto: Dto<'products'>, client: Models<'products'>): Promise<any> => {
      return await client.create({ data: dto })
    }
  ) {}
}
export const clousure = (model: keyof CreatorObject): any => {
  const creatorObject = new CreatorObject()

  const create: createMethodType<typeof model> = async (dto, client) => {
    const response = creatorObject[model]
    return response
  }
  return { create }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is the best I could Comme up with.
Ive implemented a model extension for all models with the queries i needer bassed upn this discussion. [Given name of a model, get its fields](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/18478) 
The only residual problem im seemed to have is that when i try to define the exact function params on the create, update and the rest of methods used I still ve the same problem as before.
But by using the Function type i was able to fullfill my needs but at expense of loosing some type safety.
I leave the code implemented here.

```js
import { PrismaClient, Prisma } from '@prisma/client'
import { logger } from '../logger/logger.service'
import { ResponseObject } from '../entities'
import { type IResponse } from '../index'
export class PrismaSingleton {
  static Instance: any
  constructor (
    public prisma = new PrismaClient().$extends({
      model: {
        $allModels: {
          async createGeneric<T>(
            this: T & { create: Function },
            x: Prisma.Args<T, 'create' >['data']
          ): Promise<IResponse> {
            const modelName = Prisma.getExtensionContext(this).name
            try {
              const response = await this.create({ data: x })
              return new ResponseObject(null, true, response)
            } catch (error) {
              logger.error({
                function: `${modelName as string}CreateGeneric`,
                error
              })
              return new ResponseObject(error, false, null)
            }
          },
          async updateGeneric<T>(
            this: T & { update: Function },
            data: Prisma.Args<T, 'update'>['data'],
            id: string
          ): Promise<IResponse> {
            const model = Prisma.getExtensionContext(this).name
            try {
              const response = await this.update({ where: { id }, data })
              return new ResponseObject(null, true, response)
            } catch (error) {
              logger.error({
                function: `${model as string}updateGeneric`,
                error
              })
              return new ResponseObject(error, false, null)
            }
          },
          async deleteGeneric<T>(
            this: T & { delete: Function },
            id: string
          ): Promise<IResponse> {
            const model = Prisma.getExtensionContext(this).name
            try {
              const response = await this.delete({ where: { id } })
              return new ResponseObject(null, true, response)
            } catch (error) {
              logger.error({
                function: `${model as string}DeleteGeneric`,
                error
              })
              return new ResponseObject(error, false, null)
            }
          },
          async listGeneric <T>(
            this: T & { findMany: Function }
          ): Promise<IResponse> {
            const model = Prisma.getExtensionContext(this).name
            try {
              const response = await this.findMany()
              return new ResponseObject(null, true, response)
            } catch (error) {
              logger.error({
                function: `${model as string}ListGeneric`, error
              })
              return new ResponseObject(error, false, null)
            }
          },
          async getByIdGeneric <T>(
            this: T & { findUnique: Function },
            id: string
          ): Promise<IResponse> {
            const model = Prisma.getExtensionContext(this).name
            try {
              const response = await this.findUnique({ where: { id } })
              return new ResponseObject(null, true, response)
            } catch (error) {
              logger.error({
                function: `${model as string}GetByIdGeneric`, error
              })
              return new ResponseObject(error, false, null)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })

  ) {
    if (PrismaSingleton.Instance !== undefined) return PrismaSingleton.Instance
    else PrismaSingleton.Instance = this
    return this
  }
}
```

I hope this serves the comunity and if anyone finds  how to get rid on the Function type ill apretiate it
Ive tryed a generic like

```js
type GetParams<T>=T extends {create:infer U} ? U : never
// OR even
type GetParams<T>=T extends {create:(args:infer U}:any=> ? U : never
```